# How to extract logged user comments in activity tab? (JQL or Jira Rest API)

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I need to extract user comments in a story (issuetype=story) in my jira project. What is the JQL or REST route for this ? Please help me out.

Currently I'm having the **issue id , key** , project key and fix version details. Following route (with JQL) returns me the issue but cannot find my comments.

```
https://jira.demo.com/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ABC AND issuetype = Story AND key=A1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: https://jira.demo.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/A1234

For documentation of this REST endpoint [click here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-getIssue)